# Permission denied when launch python script via bash

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, permissions, permission-denied

```
# ./scripts/replace-md5sums.py
bash: ./scripts/replace-md5sums.py: Permission denied
```

`replace-md5sums.py` has chmod 600

```
# ls -l ./scripts/replace-md5sums.py
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 661 2011-04-27 16:30 ./scripts/replace-md5sums.py
```

Comment: Show the output of `ls -l` for this program.

Comment: does the scripts directory have the x rights for your user ? (something like this in the output of `ls -l` `drwx r-x r-x`)

Comment: # ls -l ../
total 4
drwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 2011-04-27 16:42 meta-doctor

Comment: do a `chmod +x scripts`

Comment: are you the user ubuntu ? result of `whoami`

Comment: I'm root on Ubuntu LiveCD and that script is on windows partition.

Comment: try a `chmod 711 scripts` to completely exclude rights problems

Comment: Do `ls -l /scripts/replace-md5sums.py` and past the results in your question.

Comment: @r9s: Do `ls -l /scripts/replace-md5sums.py` and past the results in your question.  Not in a comment.  In the question.  Properly formatted so we can read it.

Comment: "replace-md5sums.py has chmod 777" is false.  Please remove it from the question.

Answer (score 27):

You should be able to run the script typing:

```
$ chmod 755 ./scripts/replace-md5sums.py
$ ./scripts/replace-md5sums.py
```

There are times where the user you are currently logged with just don't have the permission to change file mode bits. In such cases if you have the root password you can change the file permission this way:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 ./scripts/replace-md5sums.py
```

Comment: If you don't like to give the `x` flag you can use 744. Here to run the script you have to type `python ./scripts/replace-md5sums.py` explicitly.

Answer (score 17):

- In the terminal enter: chmod u+x script name with the '.py' extension in the end.
- Remember, u stands for user and x read, write and execute actions to the file.
- Keep in mind as well the line which must go on top of your Python script which is: #!/usr/bin/python3.9 Going on root you can easily identify what the python version and path is.
- Now re-execute it again.

Answer (score 8):

Mount your Windows partition with "exec" option - on some distros it's "noexec" by default.

Comment: I had the same problem with my XFS partition.

Answer (score 6):

I solved my problem. it's just the version of python which the interpreter reads off the first line. removing to version numbers did it for me, i.e.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7 --> #!/usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
python ./scripts/replace-md5sums.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Ubuntu user and I had the same issue, when I was trying to run python script through a bash script while files were located in a NTFS partition (even with **su** didn't work) then I've moved it home (ext4) then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first of all check if you are in the correct directory where your python script is located.
On the net, they say to run the command :

```
python3 your_file_name.py
```

But it doesn't work.
What worked for me however was:

```
python -u my_file_name.py
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#strace ./scripts/replace-md5sums.py
```

Answer (score -1):

Check for id. It may have root permissions.

So type `su` and then execute the script as `./scripts/replace-md5sums.py`.

It works.