# How to give executable permission to all Python scripts in Linux?

Tags: python, bash, path, executable, chmod

Suppose I have a python script called **a.py** like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Author    : Bhishan Poudel
# Date      : Jul 13, 2016


# Imports


# Script
print("hello")
```

I can run this scripts in two ways:
**Using python interpreter:**

```
python3 a.py
```

**Changing permission**

```
chmod a+x a.py; ./a.py
```

**QUESTION**
How can I run any new or old python scripts without using `chmod a+x script_name` all the times.

I have root access and user access both to my computer.

Basically i want executable permission to all the .py files, how can we do so?

I tried different shebangs such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
#!/usr/local/bin/env python3
```

The python interpreter is also in the $PATH.
The output of echo $PATH is following:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/opt/local/bin:/Users/poudel/phosim:/Users/poudel/Applications:/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin:/Users/poudel/Applications/Geany.app/Contents/MacOS/:/opt/local/bin:/Users/poudel/phosim:/Users/poudel/Applications:/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin:/Applications/Geany.app/Contents/MacOS/:/opt/local/bin:/Users/poudel/phosim:/Users/poudel/Applications:/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin:/Applications/Geany.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

Also, ls /usr/bin/py* has:

```
/usr/bin/pydoc*            /usr/bin/python2.5@        /usr/bin/pythonw*
/usr/bin/pydoc2.5@         /usr/bin/python2.5-config@ /usr/bin/pythonw2.5@
/usr/bin/pydoc2.6@         /usr/bin/python2.6@        /usr/bin/pythonw2.6@
/usr/bin/pydoc2.7@         /usr/bin/python2.6-config@ /usr/bin/pythonw2.7@
/usr/bin/python*           /usr/bin/python2.7@
/usr/bin/python-config*    /usr/bin/python2.7-config@
```

**Related links:**
http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-make-a-python-script-executable-on-unix.htm
[Permission Denied when executing python file in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899919/permission-denied-when-executing-python-file-in-linux)
[bash permission denied for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060612/bash-permission-denied-for-python)
[Permission denied when launch python script via bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807663/permission-denied-when-launch-python-script-via-bash)

Comment: You probably *dont* want all `.py` files to be executable; modules that aren't intended to be run as scripts should not have their executable bit set (or at least, there is no reason to set it).

Comment: @chepner, I appreciate your idea, but i wanted to run files without using chmod a+x script_name.py all the time for all the files. For future reference, I will consider your idea too. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The hard way**

Run below with root privilege:

```
find /your/path/ -type f -name "*.py" -exec chmod u+x {} \;
```

**Note:**

`chmod` need not be run as root if you're the owner of `.py` file.

**The smart way**

Write a script to take care of this.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f "$1" ]
then
geany "$1" # You could also use xdg-open if you set geany to open .py files
else
cp /path/to/python/startup/template "$1" # You may omit this if you don't have a default template
chmod u+x "$1"
geany "$1"
fi
```

Save the script as, say, `pycreator` in say `/usr/bin/` , then do

```
chown root:root /usr/bin/pycreator
chmod +x-w /usr/bin/pycreator
```

To create a new script using `pycreator`, do

```
pycreator calculator.py
```

Also [[ this ]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46010/25919) answer pointed to by [@choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba) in his comment provides valuable insight in this regard.

Comment: Also, configure your editor to add the execution flag for future .py files created.

Comment: @choroba : I  like this answer, but is it possible to configure an editor say `vi` to automatically add `+x` while saving a file with particular extension say `.sh`?

Answer (score 3):

Using the idea of @sjsam,
I did following:

Suppose I have a file hello.py in any location.

```
cd to that location
find $PWD -type f -name "*.py" -exec chmod u+x {} \;
./hello.py

# Now, i can create any number of .py files in that folder and run ./filename

# Note: if we are running as user permission, and also have sudo access,
   we can also do:
   sudo -H find $PWD -type f -name "*.py" -exec chmod u+x {} \;

We should not use sudo unless absolutely necessary.
```

Thanks to sjsam.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **chmod +x *.py** it works on my PC(OS:Ubuntu 20.4), Also i am using **#! /usr/bin/env python3** shebang