# Run Python script using virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, permission-denied

I have a python script named `utils` (note without any .py extension). Where I have some utility functions. The path is also added in PATH variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import click, sys

@main.command('echo', context_settings=dict(help_option_names=['-h', '--help']))
def echo_test():
    click.echo("Hello World")
    sys.exit(0)
```

It works fine. Now I can run from anywhere `utils echo`.

I am trying to make the script to use virtualenv instead of the global python. I have tried

```
#!/path/to/venv/bin python3

import click, sys
```

Then it throws me error `permission denied`

Permissions for `utils` file are `-rwxr-xr-x`

Any idea how could I use venv with script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission denied when launch python script via bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807663/permission-denied-when-launch-python-script-via-bash) - maybe via this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5822293/573034

Comment: Unfortunately not. This file has all the permissions

Answer (score 0):

If your code is pasted correctly, your problem is that you are trying to execute a directory with your she-bang, not Python, because you have a space rather than a slash as a separator:

`#!/path/to/venv/bin python3`

rather than:

`#!/path/to/venv/bin/python3`

EDIT: By the way, is there a reason you want to change the code and not just activate the virtual environment, like it's supposed to be used?

If you want to do it, you can just:

`$ source path/to/venv/bin/activate<.optional_extension>`

You need the optional extension if you use a shell other than Bash (probably other Bourne-like shells too).

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the file permissions via this command:

```
chmod 755
```

`chmod -R 755 on the /usr/lib/python/site-packages/virtualenv`

or even

```
chmod +x
```

Suggest you read the man page for chmod by using this command

```
man chmod
```

if you are not sure.

Comment: It's not a file permission issue. The utils file have all the necessary permission.

Comment: Juts found this-

`sudo chown -R your_username:your_username path/to/virtuaelenv/`


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471972/how-to-avoid-permission-denied-when-using-pip-with-virtualenv

Comment: I haven't created venv as a root user. Anyway I have tried this. It didn't work :(